# How can I crop a video on Android phone

Tags: android, video, ffmpeg

I am currently making an application where I need to crop a video in a square. I already made my surface preview display a square with strategically placed overlays (making the surface iew a square distorts the video). After I save it to the path and before uploading to my server, is there a way I can crop the bounds (Like bitmap cropping) and then upload it to my server. I can use ffmpeg but that gets server intensive with a lot of users and is not a viable solution.

Any guidance would be much appreciated.

Comment: You might be better off just taking care of this on the video itself (if this is a possibility i.e. reencoding it, cropping out the sides from the source video) this will save your server some bandwidth, and the clients some cpu power, as they won't be decoding the edges that are getting blocked out anyways.

Comment: I am kind of confused on what this means?

Comment: If you have the physical videos (you're not streaming them from elsewhere) You can take them and crop them on a pc, then use the cropped videos within your process.

Comment: What? why would I do that? This is within an app (users record the video) and upload them to my server. I need the phone to be able to crop the video.

Comment: "I can use ffmpeg but that gets server intensive with a lot of users and is not a viable solution" -- it is definitely a viable solution, and it is certainly what I would recommend. You're welcome to use `ffmpeg`  on the client side to attempt your cropping, but that's more challenging to implement.

Comment: @CommonsWare do you think it is a scalable solution though? Imagine 10k people trying to upload videos at the same time? I would wind up paying much more in bandwidth rather than some client solution where it is cropped and rotated appropriately and all I would have to do is upload and save it like IOS.

Comment: "Imagine 10k people trying to upload videos at the same time?" -- 10K simultaneous uploads would imply a user base of >100M users, at which point you will have already been acquired by some firm that can maintain an adequate server farm.

Comment: @CommonsWare lol a guy can dream no?  But in all seriousness... even a 10-100 gets taxing plus pictures and whatever else is going on no? also ffmpeg is a blocking process which will hang a users activity indicator making them think my app is slow. Also my ffmpeg build is ffmpeg-php and for some reason I Cannot use h264 vencoder nor can I use any other filters. such as rotate (which is my other issue), all vidoes are rotated 90 deg

Comment: "ffmpeg is a blocking process which will hang a users activity indicator making them think my app is slow" -- done properly, `ffmpeg` is not "a blocking process" on either the client or server side. With regards to your server problems, if you cannot get your server environment to work the way you want, when that can be completely under your control, how do you expect to get 100M Android devices to work the way you want, when you control approximately 0 of them?

Comment: I totally agree with that statement @CommonsWare. So you would suggest doing some sort of server side implementation rather than client?

Comment: All else being equal, I'd do the work on the server. There could be some reasons why you have to do the work on the client (e.g., they need to be able to consume the video, in square format, without Internet connectivity), but if a server has to be part of the mix, I'd do the work there. Much easier to fix bugs in one central spot.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59289/discussion-between-dnaso-and-commonsware).

Comment: Yea that would be my only issue, is then it prevents me from letting the user save the video on their phone like they do on IOS . I guess I'll have to do some research. thanks @CommonsWare